# jquery.trim compared to string.trim

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

Is there any difference between jQuery trim and native JavaScript one?

Is there any other behaviour, safety, performance?

Comment: Why not to peek [the source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.trim)?

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript `.trim()` was defined in ES 5.1, and will **not work for IE<9**. Therefore, if you already use jQuery you could use the less performant `$.trim()`

---

**jQuery's** `$.trim()` Method does:

```
trim: function( text ) {
    return text == null ? "" : ( text + "" ).replace( rtrim, "" );
}
```

where `rtrim` is basically this RegExp

```
new RegExp( "^" + whitespace + "+|((?:^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\.)*)" + whitespace + "+$", "g" )
```

and `whitespace` is represented as this Group:

```
"[\\x20\\t\\r\\n\\f]"
```

---

In [**JavaScript** (ES6)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.trim) it's defined as:

> 21.1.3.25 String.prototype.trim ( )
>
> This function interprets a String value as a sequence of UTF-16 encoded code points, as described in 6.1.4.
>
> The following steps are taken:
>   Let O be RequireObjectCoercible(this value).
>   Let S be ToString(O).
>   ReturnIfAbrupt(S).
>   Let T be a String value that is a copy of S with both leading and trailing white space removed. The definition of white space is the union of WhiteSpace and LineTerminator. When determining whether a Unicode code point is in Unicode general category “Zs”, code unit sequences are interpreted as UTF-16 encoded code point sequences as specified in 6.1.4.
>   Return T.
>   NOTE The trim function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be a String object. Therefore, it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

So let alone the implementation of JS's `.trim()` to browser vendors, the point is quite clear:
Remove any representation of newlines or spaces from the beginning and end of a String.

Answer (score 1):

**String.trim**

The trim() method removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

Note: The trim() method does not change the original string.

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

**jquery.trim()**

The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string.

If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved