# How do I truncate and add ellipses to text that's longer than a specific number of words?

Tags: javascript, text, truncate

I figured out how to truncate text, but I only want to add ellipsis if the text is more than 10 words long.  If the text is shorter than 10 words, I don't want ellipsis to show.

My code truncates the text the way I want it, but I don't want ellipsis for shorter text.
How can I accomplish that?

```
var shortText = jQuery.trim(title).split(" ").slice(0, 10).join(" ") + "...";
```

Comment: When you say "words" do you really mean "characters"?

Comment: Check the length of the array returned by split. If it's at least 10, add the ellipsis.

Comment: "How can I accomplish that?" by having an IF / ELSE block. You are ALWAYS adding ellipsis. Not just when length of array is bigger than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add the ellipsis conditionally, based on the total number of words.
Since [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an array, you can test against the array's [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

```js
function truncateText(text) {

  text = text.trim();
  let words = text.split(" ");

  return words.length > 10
    ? words.slice(0, 10).join(" ") + "..."
    : text;

}

console.log(
  truncateText("This is a sentence that is more than ten words long.")
);

console.log(
  truncateText("This is a shorter sentence.")
);
```

Incidentally, jQuery is [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329177/jquery-trim-compared-to-string-trim) not necessary since `trim()`, `split()`, `join()`, `slice()`, and `length` are all standard (plain) JavaScript.

Comment: This also works very well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
title.trim().split(" ")
  .slice(0,11)
// function (e,i){ i<10? e : '...' }
  .map( (e,i) => i < 10? e : '...' )
  .join(' ')
```

The `map` function will replace the 11th element, if present, with the elipsis

---

**Side effect**: this will join the ellipsis with an space

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Very eloquent, but doesn't work in IE 11 for some reason.  I did some research and in theory IE 11 should support the array.map, but the code doesn't work in IE... the other browsers it works fine.

Comment: @sullivansg Lol, that remembers me the old IE6 times. May you try replacing the arrow function with `function (e,i){ i<10? e : '...' }`? I'm curious, but don't have a box with windows at hand